# Redirect old urls to new url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect

```
domain.com/games-10/my-game to domain.com
domain.com/games-10/yours-game to domain.com
domain.com/games-10/his-game to domain.com
```

I have tried:

```
Rewriterule ^games-10/(.*)$ http://domain.com$1 [r=301, L]
RewriteRule ^games-10/([^/]+)/?$ http://domain.com [R=301, L]
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should totally work :)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^games-10/.*$ http://domain.com [R=301,L]
```